# 2020 Moderator Election – Results

Tags: discussion, election

German Language's [second moderator election](https://german.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three official moderators are:

[image: Wrzlprmft] [image: guidot] [image: jonathan.scholbach]

They'll replace the pro-tem moderators and show up on [the dashboard](https://german.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly. Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

We should also spare a thanks for the moderators who served the site so far as pro-tems!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6159496343715840/0).

Comment: Imagine clapping, hugs, confetti and fireworks!

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators and many thanks everyone who candidated! And three cheers to the old ones for their work and dedication :)

Answer (score 22):

A particular thanks goes to Takkat, who moderated and shaped this site for eight years and didn’t run in the election.

Answer (score 8):

My Congratulations to all new and old moderators.
May the community be with you!

Edit: and many thanks to all voting participants!

Comment: Thank you! Also thank you, again, for your candidature! And thanks for contributing your good work!